# Jpanel with toolbar and title

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java Swing.I want to design one JToolBar. The JToolBar should be placed on the right of JPanel with the minimize, restore and close icons just like the one shown in the image below:-

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrqIl.png]

```
    panelCont.setLayout(cl);
                JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
                titlePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
                panel1.createToolTip();
                panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Add Products"));

                JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                JLabel lab = new JLabel("Add Company");
                JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);
                JButton btn = new JButton("Add");

                gbc.gridx = 2;
                gbc.gridy = 1;
                gbc.weightx= 0.5;
                gbc.ipadx = 0;
//              gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 10, 10, 0);
                panel2.add(lab, gbc);

                gbc.gridx = 2;
                gbc.gridy = 2;
                gbc.weightx= 0.5;
                gbc.ipadx = 0;
//              gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 10, 10, 0);
                panel2.add(tf, gbc);

                gbc.gridx = 2;
                gbc.gridy = 3;
                gbc.weightx= 0.5;
                gbc.ipadx = 0;
//              gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 10, 10, 0);
                panel2.add(btn, gbc);

                titlePanel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panel1);
                titlePanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel2);
                panelCont.add(titlePanel, "1");
//              panelCont.set
                cl.show(panelCont, "1");
//              frame1.add(BorderLayout.CENTER , titlePanel);
                frame1.add(BorderLayout.CENTER , panelCont);
                frame1.setVisible(true);

            }
```

i have written that but didn't get the desired output please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"The JToolBar should be placed on the right of JPanel with the minimize, restore and close icons*" - So you mean like a `JInternalFrame`?

Comment: You could just a `GridBagLayout` on the panel instead.